# How to manipulate lists under table column in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have this code

```
<table><tr><td class="product-name">Product Name</td><td class="product-price"><ul class="wcsatt-options overrides_exist">
            <li class="one-time-option">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="cart[511e54615e04fe5b038663461729f5ec][convert_to_sub]" value="0" checked="checked">
                <span class="one-time-option-details"><span class="one-time-option-price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>34,00<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span></span></span>                </label>
        </li>
                <li class="subscription-option">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="cart[511e54615e04fe5b038663461729f5ec][convert_to_sub]" value="3_month">
                <span class="subscription-option-details"><span class="price subscription-price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>28,90<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span> <span class="subscription-details"> chaque 3 mois</span></span></span>                </label>
        </li>
                <li class="subscription-option">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="cart[511e54615e04fe5b038663461729f5ec][convert_to_sub]" value="4_month">
                <span class="subscription-option-details"><span class="price subscription-price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>28,90<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span> <span class="subscription-details"> chaque 4 mois</span></span></span>                </label>
        </li>
                <li class="subscription-option">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="cart[511e54615e04fe5b038663461729f5ec][convert_to_sub]" value="6_month">
                <span class="subscription-option-details"><span class="price subscription-price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>28,90<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span> <span class="subscription-details"> chaque 6 mois</span></span></span>                </label>
        </li>
    </ul></td></tr>
```

Product Name
                
                
                    
                    34,00€                
            
                    
                
                    
                    28,90€  chaque 3 mois                
            
                    
                
                    
                    28,90€  chaque 4 mois                
            
                    
                
                    
                    28,90€  chaque 6 mois

I just want to hide the option li class "one-time-option" if one of the radio button from subscription class is checked. And also if the class one-time-option radio button is checked all class under subscription class will hidden. Can you help me to do this in jquery. Thanks

Comment: You can break down your issues into smaller problem. You need to 1. Add onclick / onselect listener to your option 2. Find the `li` element 3. hide and hide it. All of this can be found on SO.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is related high order function  , that take a function as input
all of thing with this paradigm  `if happen then take this task` in java script
is sloved  event listener
event listener  is made  similary  below example

```js
function anotherEventListener(typeOfEvent,callback){
//detect Event code ...

var eventThatHappen={
    eventType:"keypress",
    key:"p",
    durationOfKeypress:2
}
if (eventThatHappen.eventType==="keypress"){
    callback(eventThatHappen); /* eventThatHappen ~ e ~ evt ~ event */
}}
```

in there argument event passed to function that you say which item selected

```js
$(".btn").click(function(){
console.log(this)
})
```

in jquery  with `console.log` see data `this`
event listener is given all data about  that selected item